# how to add slider in tool mode?

Tags: slider, godot

I'm trying to add a slider in tool mode like this:

[image]

code:

```
tool
extends Position2D

export(float) var CustomSlider = 0.1 setget changeSlider_x

func changeSlider_x(changed_val):
    CustomSlider=changed_val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I want to point out that this variable:

```
export(float) var CustomSlider = 0.1
```

Is a variant. Even thought Godot shows it as a float on the inspector panel.

This is a float and Godot will also show it as float in the inspector panel:

```
export var CustomSlider := 0.1
```

Or if you prefer the type to be explicit, you can write it like this:

```
export var CustomSlider:float = 0.1
```

---

What you specify between parenthesis after `export` is to controls how it will be shown in the inspector panel.

*I know the documentation is a little hard to find - because there are other things called "export" - but here it is: [GDScript exports](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html)*

Now, to get a (useful) slider, you have to either:

- Specify a range of values:

  ```
  export(float, 0, 10) var CustomSlider:
  ```
- Specify a range of values, with snapping to a step size:

  ```
  export(float, 0, 10, 0.1) var CustomSlider:
  ```

  The snapping will be to a multiple of the step size. That is, the snapping is not offset by the minimum and maximum.
- Specify an exponential slider, with a maximum greater than zero (the minimum will be zero):

  ```
  export(float, EXP, 10) var CustomSlider:
  ```

  With this the slider is not linear. You will find that at the half point the value is the square root of the maximum, not the half. And a third of the way, you find the cubic root of the maximum, and so on. As a result, number are more tightly packed near the maximum (e.g. for a range from 0 to 100, the half point is 10, so the first half goes from 0 to 10 and the second half goes from 10 to 100).
- Specify an exponential slider, with a minimum and a maximum:

  ```
  export(float, EXP, 10, 100) var CustomSlider:
  ```

  This is similar to the behavior above, except it is offset so the minimum is not zero, but the one you specified.
- Specify an exponential slider, with a minimum, a maximum, and snapping to a step size:

  ```
  export(float, EXP, 10, 100, 2) var CustomSlider:
  ```

  This creates an exponential slider similar to the previous case. Except this one will snap the value, similar to the snapping described before.

---

Aside from using `export`, there is another way to have something show in the inspector panel: use `_get_property_list` (requires a `tool` script), which would give us more control (some options are only available this way). Furthermore, we could call `property_list_changed_notify` to tell Godot to check again what it should show in the inspector panel, and that would allow you to have it change dynamically.

---

By the way, you can write your variable name in lower caps and with `_`, and Godot will capitalize it and replace the `_` with spaces when it shows it in the inspector panel.

Comment: ah yes the lord and saviour himself, thank you as always!
and as far as I know the documentation is very scarce when it comes to tool mode, makes it really difficult

Comment: for some reason `const UPPER=10` `export(float, 0, UPPER, 0.1) var CustomSlider:` isn't working and gives an error  `Expected a number as upper bound in the numeric range hint.`

Comment: @cakelover As you found out the GDScript parser expects a numeric literal there, it does not support a named constant. And - after testing - apparently the equivalent for Godot 4.0 isn't supported either. If you have an use case for this, please consider writing a proposal at: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals

Comment: Is this possible in C# for godot?

Comment: @ShemTom See C# API differences to GDScript ([3.5](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_differences.html#export-keyword), [4.1](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.1/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_differences.html#export-annotation))